# Accessing the localStorage of one device from another in react-native

Tags: react-native, local-storage

Some days before, i saw a blog post about why we need to keep whatsapp open on our smartphone to make it work on our PC.

It said that WhatsApp fetches the data (messages) from our smartphone and shows them on our pc which seems pretty good as it will lower the load on our database.

So now i wanted to know if there is a way to do so in react-native i.e, access the localStorage of one device from another.

Why i want to do that?

I am building an app where in the profile, i also take the profile picture from the user and i don't want to store it on the database but instead store it locally and serve it from there.

The reason for that is that we need buckets to store media files and serve them from there and i wanted to cut that part when deploying my app.

Comment: Local storage is *local*. You can't access it from another device.

Comment: Then how does whatsapp access it. Maybe i am wrong about local storage, but what i mean is if there is such a way to access some data from one device using another device, maybe first getting the permission from the user.  Making some part of the device to act like a server.

Comment: Probably they store it somewhere else in the cloud.

Comment: Actually storing it somewhere else in the cloud has no point. Why they will shift data from one database to another and even if it is right we should be able to access that from any source where we are logged in but we need to keep the app open on our phone

Comment: You definitely won't be able to "access the localStorage of one device from another" in any built-in way. You'll need to build something that:

1. On the source device, reads the local storage

2. On the source device, takes that information and transmits it somewhere, even if that's temporary storage

3. On the target device, receives it and does the thing with it

From what you said in the comment above, you already know this. Seems a pretty niche thing to have a good library available, but those are the basics.

Comment: @JamesClover thanks for the comment. But the point is i have to do it multiple times, so i have to connect to the device multiple times and get the data because it is not on the database. BTW it seems tough as it is also a security concern , trying to get the data from devices instead of server.

Comment: It is most definitely tough - which is why folks will generally pull the data into some kind of repository from one client and then transmit it to another. Media buckets, ya know. What your are thinking of doing to simplify things is likely to make things more complicated.

Comment: Yeah you are right. What i wanted to do is making it more difficult, But i thought maybe there is a way.